# How can I export the motion tracking markers to csv?

Tags: python, export, motion-capture

The blender motion tracking markers are very convenient to use but it seems there is no direct way to export the path of the markers themselves.

Is there a way to export the paths of multiple motion tracking markers to a csv or other text file?

(I found this [script](http://scummos.blogspot.jp/2012/11/blender-exporting-camera-tracking.html) but it seems to only work if the marker is set at frame 0, my markers are added at various frames)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The script on [this github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5663418) page can export the data of each motion tracking marker.